# Remove folder confusion

Tags: wix, windows-installer, directory

Using WiX, I'm replacing a application with a new version.
In the old version, there was a directory which is no longer needed in the new version.
So on install, this should do it:

```
<Component Id="killDir_" Guid="..." KeyPath="yes">
    <RemoveFolder Id="killDir" On="both" />
</Component>
```

So far so good, this works fine.

**But if the folder is already removed, the setup creates it again!**

This happens also when using

```
<util:RemoveFolderEx .../>
```

---

I have tried a condition within the `<Component>` tag:

```
<Condition>OLD_STUFF_EXISTS</Condition>
```

along with a `DirectorySearch` in the Product:

```
<Property Id="OLD_STUFF_EXISTS">
    <DirectorySearch Id='DirSearch' Path="OldDir" Depth='0'>
    </DirectorySearch>
</Property>
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

In the MSI log file, the RemoveFolder seems to be executed:

```
MSI (s) (A0:4C) [13:44:45:742]: Doing action: RemoveFolders
MSI (s) (A0:4C) [13:44:45:742]: Note: 1: 2205 2:  3: ActionText 
Action 13:44:45: RemoveFolders. Removing folders
Action start 13:44:45: RemoveFolders.
Action ended 13:44:45: RemoveFolders. Return value 1.
```

Some lines down, the istalled creates it again:

```
MSI (s) (A0:4C) [13:44:45:807]: Executing op: FolderCreate(Folder=C:\...\,Foreign=0,,)
```

**Is there any way to tell the installer NOT to create it again?**

Comment: In what directory element is your RemoveFolder component located? Did you try moving it to TARGETDIR? In your compiled MSI, are there entries in the CreateFolder table? (this table may not be present at all).

Comment: @SteinÅsmul: No, it's a separate directory: `<SetDirectory Id="OldDir" Value="..." />` and it's completely different from TARGETDIR.

Comment: If this is a major upgrade, say where it is sequenced. A folder is created when files are installed there, and when files are removed by the uninstall, then the folder will normally be removed, unusual to remove folders from older products in an upgrade. Also possibile that component guids are the same in old and new and are preserving the folder. Your folder create log extract doesn't show a folder called KillDir, just something else. It would better to an ordinary upgrade and post the complete verbose log.